# Serilog Console logging into multible console windows

Tags: console, serilog

Is it possible to setup serilog console sink to log into different console windows? I would like to split logging from logs based on namespace into different console windows just like I can do that with files.
The current workaround is, to do the logging into files and run tail -f on the files.
But that way the color information of the Console Output is lost and I like to keep an eye on the look looking at the color code in my dev environment .